# Android layout gravity not Working

Tags: android, android-layout, gravity, layout-gravity

I have an xml file that contains a `ScrollView`  and inside there is a `LinearLayout`; this layout also contains 2 more layouts:

1st is where data will be added dynamically

2nd is a just something that needs to be displayed **at the bottom** of the view.

But gravity isn't working, I've tried both `gravity` and `layout_gravity` but none work, all layouts are set to fill the parent so why is this happening?

The copyright layout must be inside the `ScrollView` but at the bottom of the screen even if `ScrollView` is empty (1st layout).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/istoricLayout"
    android:visibility="visible" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/istoric"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom" //here I'm trying to move this at the buttom
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/thick_bar_height"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/bar_vertical_space"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/bar_vertical_space"
                    android:background="@color/white" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/versiuneaCompleta"
                    android:layout_width="250dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:background="@color/color2"
                    android:text="Vizioneaza versiunea completa"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="250dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:background="@color/white" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:src="@drawable/support_right_icon" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:src="@drawable/support_left_icon" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:background="@color/white"
                        android:text="Support +40.XXX.XXX.XXX"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="@color/color2"
                        android:textSize="15dp" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Politica de condidentialitate ·"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="10dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text=" Despre noi ·"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="10dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text=" Contact"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="10dp" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="© 2013 Artcos Design. All Rights Reserved"
                    android:textColor="@color/copyRightColor"
                    android:textSize="10dp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It's nice that you've provided your support number. I will call you in the middle of the night :P

Comment: well then, someone has that number :D

Comment: I removed it just so nobody will be disturbed, although I dont expect that

Answer (score 2):

Based on the comments to @Doomsknight's answer, set `android:fillViewPort="true"` on your `ScrollView`.

Height attribute on scroll view's child is ignored (if it was respected, the whole scroll view would be useless). Setting `fillViewPort="true"` makes the scroll view child expand to parent height if it is less than parent height and otherwise the attribute does nothing. This way your child `LinearLayout` in the scroll view will be at least as tall as the scroll view's parent, making the gravity work the way you want.

In addition, make the child `LinearLayout` heights to `wrap_content` and assign the first `LinearLayout` a non-zero `layout_weight`. You can also remove the `bottom` `layout_gravity`.

Comment: I dont know why but , it's not working. It sounds good in theory but not so well in practice.

Answer (score 2):

Change the whole thing to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/istoricLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/thick_bar_height"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/bar_vertical_space"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/bar_vertical_space"
            android:background="@color/white" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/versiuneaCompleta"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="@color/color2"
            android:text="Vizioneaza versiunea completa"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="15dp" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="@color/white" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:src="@drawable/support_right_icon" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:src="@drawable/support_left_icon" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:text="Support +40.766.154.894"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/color2"
                android:textSize="15dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Politica de condidentialitate ·"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="10dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=" Despre noi ·"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="10dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=" Contact"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="10dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="© 2013 Artcos Design. All Rights Reserved"
            android:textColor="@color/copyRightColor"
            android:textSize="10dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottomLayout" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/istoric"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**EDIT**
Setting referenced dimensions, colors and images to something meaningful, the layout looks something like below image (for clarity, the ScrollView has a red background and bottomLayout has a yellow background).
[image]

As you can see `bottomLayout` is on the bottom.

Comment: I looks as it should but if ScrollView has a lot of elements will it still look as if the copyright layout is inside the ScrollView and not always at the bottom? I can't really test this as the API I need are still in development and that is a task for another guy.

Comment: Well it's not adding it to the bottom of the scroll view but I changed my mind and prefer it this way. However the question is still not answered so keep trying. I haven't accepted an answer yet.

Comment: Strange ... I've checked the layout on a sample project and `bottomLayout` is put on the bottom. I've updated my answer for this.

Comment: Yes it is on the bottom, BUT I want it to be pushed down, outside of the screen, when there is a lot of data in the scrollview and still be able to scroll down and see it again. I really beginning to think this is not possible with xml only.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this link, it contains the explanation for your problem:

http://www.curious-creature.org/2010/08/15/scrollviews-handy-trick/

The android:fillViewport of the ScrollView should be set to true which allows the child view to expand itself to fill the ScrollView's height. 
Then, pick one child element that is going to be expanded in order to fill the empty space and set its layout_weight to 1 (assuming LinearLayout is used). That element is usually the one right above the widget that is intended to be placed right at the bottom.

The XML file should look something like this:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <!-- widget 1 -->
        <!-- widget 2 -->
        <!-- ... -->
        <!-- widget n -->

        <!-- this widget expands to fill the empty space -->
        <TextView
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">
        </TextView>

        <!-- this copyright layout is going to be placed rock bottom -->
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="© 2013 Artcos Design. All Rights Reserved"
            android:textColor="@color/copyRightColor"
            android:textSize="10dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Move your textview, below the scrollview.   You are using gravity in the wrong manner.

I assume you want your copyright at the bottom fixed.

Gravity is used to display contents of the view, in certain ways. or how to position the view itself, but it will not change the view hierarchy.

```
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

 <TextView
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="© 2013 Artcos Design. All Rights Reserved"
   android:textColor="@color/copyRightColor"
    android:textSize="10dp" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

you will also need to change the scroll view, so it does not take the screen height, but instead will best fill the area leaving room for copyright notice:

```
 <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
```

Comment: but I want the copyright to be in the 'ScrollView' but if the ScrollView is empty (or very few elements) to appear at the bottom.

Comment: I'm starting to think this isn't really possible with xml alone

Comment: @MihaiBratulescu Then put your `textview` after the `linearlayout` that is inside the `scrollview`, and make that `linearlayout` height = 0dip, and weight = 1 as shown above. That will cause it to take up as much space as avaliable but leaving space for your copyright. (unless there is no space, so will have to scroll to see it)

Comment: You can't add two elements in a ScrollView, that is the reason for the first LinearLayout in scroll (to contain more elements)

Comment: @MihaiBratulescu Sorry yes, do this to the inner Linearlayout